# How to retrieve data from .php and display in <select> within Cordova hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cordova

I am writing a hybrid app using Visual Studio with Cordova exetnstion and trying to pull data from www.a.com/b.php

My b.php code is:

```
<?php
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("http://www.yo.com", "ya", "ye") or die (mysql_error());

// Select database
mysql_select_db("oh") or die(mysql_error());

// SQL query
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Properties ORDER BY number DESC";

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array


echo '<select name="Address" id="address_search" style="width:282px; display:block;" required>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 
{
   // Write the value of the full address including unit code, address, city, state, zipcode (which is now in the array $row)
   echo '<option value="'. $row['number'] . ", " . $row['address'] . ", " . $row['city'] . ", " . $row['state'] . ", " . $row['zipcode'] .'">' 
    . $row['number'] . ", " . $row['address'] . ", " . $row['city'] . ", " . $row['state'] . ", " . $row['zipcode'] . 
    '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';


// Close the database connection
mysql_close();?>
```

I already add select tag form directly in php code, but I don't know how to display the whole select box (with options being retrieved data) in .html.
Any help or tutorial? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue like this:

First, in the server side-code (php in this case), in "file.php", I have an array with the database elements and I do the following:

```
$arrayElements = json_encode($arrayElements );
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . $arrayElements . ');';
```

After that, in the app js code, I use jQuery method $.getJSON() for getting the php array we prepare before. When the function get the server answer, then execute the code inside. Note that the variable "respuestaServer" is the array you have sent from php file, so you can go throw it with a loop and taking its values to your select (if you need to pass variables to your php file and receive them via GET just add the js variables inside the {}, in this example I send the variable datosUsuario and in php I receive it $_GET['usuario']).

```
var archivoValidacion = "http://example.com/file.php?jsoncallback=?";
var select = document.getElementById("idSelect");
$.getJSON( archivoValidacion, { usuario:datosUsuario ,password:datosPassword})
.done(function(respuestaServer) {
    for(var i = 0; i < respuestaServer.length;i++){          
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(respuestaServer[i]);
        option.appendChild(textNode);
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
```

})

I hope this can help you. If you have some questions just tweet me @ulisesveraes ;)

Answer (score 0):

it is not clear how you call this code

I suppose you do this with jQuery ajax function

so your code will like something this

```
$('box-selector').load('b.php');
```